# Why does iterating over weeks go wrong with PHP date?

Tags: php, date, dst

I'm writing a php script that iterates over the Monday of each week.

However the script seemed to get out of sync after 22nd of October.

```
<?php

$october_8th = strtotime("2012-10-08");

$one_week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;

$october_15th = $october_8th + $one_week;
$october_22nd = $october_15th + $one_week;
$october_29th = $october_22nd + $one_week;
$november_5th = $october_29th + $one_week;

echo date("Y-m-d -> l", $october_8th) . '<br />';
echo date("Y-m-d -> l", $october_15th) . '<br />';
echo date("Y-m-d -> l", $october_22nd) . '<br />';
echo date("Y-m-d -> l", $october_29th) . '<br />';
echo date("Y-m-d -> l", $november_5th) . '<br />';
```

This would output:

```
2012-10-08 -> Monday
2012-10-15 -> Monday
2012-10-22 -> Monday
2012-10-28 -> Sunday
2012-11-04 -> Sunday
```

I would expect it to say the 29th of October but it gets stuck at the 28th.

How should I get around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A preferred choice would be to use PHP's date-related classes to get the dates.

These classes importantly handle the daylight-savings boundaries for you, in a way that manually adding a given number of seconds to a Unix timestamp (the number from `strtotime()` that you used) cannot.

The following example takes your start dates and loops four times, each time adding a week to the date.

```
$start_date  = new DateTime('2012-10-08');
$interval    = new DateInterval('P1W');
$recurrences = 4;

foreach (new DatePeriod($start_date, $interval, $recurrences) as $date) {
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d -> l') . '<br/>';
}
```

PHP Manual links:

- [The `DatePeriod` class](http://php.net/dateperiod)
- [The `DateInterval` class](http://php.net/dateinterval)
- [The `DateTime` class](http://php.net/datetime)

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed the elegant solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

While writing this question I discovered that day light saving time ends at the 28th of October.

Because the date at initialization doesn't contain a specific time automatically midnight is assigned. This however yields a problem when summertime ends. Suddenly the time isn't midnight anymore but one hour before that AND thus a day earlier then you would expect.

An easy fix would be to initialize the time to be midday instead of midnight:

```
$october_8th = strtotime("2012-10-08 12:00");
```

Perhaps there might be more elegant solution (you're welcome to leave one), but this will do for this purpose.